# Unable to delete a post in news feed using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

At first I used my app (on facebook canvas) with publish_stream permission to create a post using Graph API, it was success, the post appeared both in my news feed and my timeline. However, when I called Graph API to delete it, using HTTP DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/{post-id}/?access_token={my-access-token}. It returned true, mean that the post is deleted successfully. But it's only deleted on my timeline and still appear in news feed, i can still comment and like it.

Please, tell me what's wrong with it? In the document, they (facebook) didn't mention this.
How can I delete a post in news feed if my app created this?

Comment: Can you show us the code that you're using to DELETE the post?

Comment: I called an HTTP DELETE to https://graph.facebook.com / {post-id}/?access_token={my-access-token}. It returned true.

Comment: Did you use an App Access Token or a User Access Token?

Comment: It was user access token with publish_stream permission. I can create a post using it.

Comment: But you said that you were using your APP to create the post. In that case, you need the App Access Token to delete the post completely.

Comment: I just try, but the result is similar, it's only delete in timeline and still available in news feed.

Comment: What language are you developing in? Are you sure your HTTP client supports the DELETE method? Some don't - e.g. javascript. Try appending a "method=delete" to the URL? https://graph.facebook.com/COMMENT_ID?method=delete

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/deleting/